# How would you manage security and setup this on TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We have one large project in TFS. We currently have a few development groups: let's say for this example there is DevTeam1, DevTeam2, DevTeam3. Our current TFS project is laid out as follows (assume there are 100+ projects and about 10 DevTeams):

```
Master Project
   |----- Common
   |----- Project1
   |----- Project2
   |----- Project3
```

- DevTeam1 works (makes changes to) on Project1, Project2, Project3 and Common (everything).
- DevTeam2 works on Project1 only but would like read-only access to Common.
- DevTeam3 works on Project1 & Project2 and would also like Read-Only access to Common.

Assuming that if a certain DevTeam is not working on a project and they shouldn't see the project at all, how would you set this up in TFS?

PS: We looked at setting up "Areas" but not clear how it all goes together after you set up an "Area" or whether this is the right path.

Comment: Are you talking about how to organize the source control repository, or how to organize work items, or both?

Comment: We don't really use work items as I believe that is just issue tracking which we do in another system so just thinking about how to organize team project or maybe break up into multiple team projects to satisfy the permissions requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the link on TWA for your project

> `http://servername:8080/tfs/collectionName/masterProjectName/_admin/_versioncontrol`

then click the source control directories of the projects. On the right side you can add your teams and give the permissions seperately to the directories.